# NSFetchRequest Returns Fault from Core Data iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to fetch the stateName in below code and show it in a label. but it always returns fault.

```
-(NSArray *) getStateNameFromCode :(NSString *) stateCode
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *objectContext = [self managedObjectContext ];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:ENTITY_STATES inManagedObjectContext:objectContext];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", COLUMN_STATE_CODE, stateCode];
    NSLog(@"Predicate : %@" ,predicate);
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[ NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSArray *stateName  = [objectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:Nil];
    if (stateName.count > 0)
    {
        return [stateName objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    return  nil ;

}

 self.labelTeams.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n" ,
                            [sharedController getStateNameFromCode:_checklist.stateHomeTeam]]
                            ;
```

OUTPUT:

```
 <States: 0xa571560> (entity: States; id: 0xa565300 <x-coredata://D6B54D51-4556-41E1-A372-F39EB871A076/States/p8> ; data: <fault>)
```

Tried using setreturnsobjectsasfaults=NO but thats not working. found so many links most of them say to use setreturnsobjectsasfaults . I killing my brian.
Any ideas will be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: What do you mean it returns a fault? Can you show what you are doing to see this fault?

Comment: Can you also output your NSPredicate log results.

Comment: Also, you're outputting an NSArray? Are you sure you're not meant to be outputting a NSString or even the State (NSManagedObject subclass).

Comment: @Fogmeister pls have a look into the edit.

Comment: I've seen it. Not sure what it means. What is that output from? Where are you getting that info from?

Comment: I think you need to update your method here. You say you are returning an NSArray but then you return a single NSManagedObject and then you are treating it like an NSString. Data faults are fine. Nothing wrong with them. You just need to get the data from it `state.name;` for instance.

Comment: return [stateName objectAtIndex:0]; is really a NSManagedObject or an array element? did i miss something.

Comment: Yes, both of those are correct. It is a single object from an array. It is also an NSManagedObject. It is **NOT** and array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
//return state name as NSString (assumes state name is string type)
-(NSString *) getStateNameFromCode :(NSString *) stateCode
{
    ....

    NSArray *states  = [objectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:Nil];
    if (states.count > 0)
    {
        //Matched state object
        NSManagedObject *state = [states objectAtIndex:0];
        //or States *state = [states objectAtIndex:0];, if States is the NSManagedObject subclass name
        return //return name of state from state object, like state.name

    }

    return  nil ;

}

 self.labelTeams.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n" ,
                            [sharedController getStateNameFromCode:_checklist.stateHomeTeam]]
                            ;
```

Comment: Ah, yeah might be the problem :)

Comment: @Fogmeister I've updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out to highlight relevant part only. :)

Comment: akhilrajtr what will happen if i return [states objectAtIndex:0];? What do you mean by ../return name of state from state object?

Comment: @LUI Array `states` contains `NSManagedObject` subclass (State entities) objects that matches the predicate as elements. So `objectAtIndex:0` will also be `NSManagedObject` subclass, ie a State entity. Return state name from that entity.